# How to count total number of chars in float number

Tags: java, double, decimal

Could you help me to write a method with the following signature:

```
public int method(double value)
```

that returns total number of chars in value(including the decimal point), for example:

```
method(5.0) - 3
method(1.2345) - 6
method(2.34) - 4
```

The problem is that method(5) must return 1, not 3, looking at 5 as it is 5.0

Comment: Convert value to string. Then string.length().

Comment: Why not converting to string and finding it's length? Is there any limitation?

Comment: I guess the answer is public int method(double value) {
        if (value == (int) value)
            return Integer.toString((int)value).length();
        else return Double.toString(value).length();
    }

Comment: @EdisonMiranda check out my answer, I think it is what you wanted

Answer (score 4):

Change the value argument to string and find its length as follow:

```
String valueString = value+"";
int count = valueString.length()
```

Do this inside your **method()**

**Update:**

```
public static int method(double value){
        String temp;
         if(value == (long) value)
                temp = String.format("%d",(long)value);
            else
                temp = String.format("%s",value);
        return temp.length();
    }
```

--

```
Input: 5.01 gives Output: 4
Input: 5.0 gives Output: 1
```

Comment: the problem is that if double is 5(actually integer) method will return 3, interpreting 5 as 5.0 so firstly we have to check if value is integer

Comment: I have tested this. Please verify.

Comment: Why did you just remove the tick mark. I solved your problem at first. Didn't I?

Comment: he seems to enjoy down-voting people :)

Comment: He first thanked me for solving his problem. Then he accepted my answer as correct and finally removed it as correct answer. Don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First , convert the double to string, and then calculate its size.

```
String str = String.valueOf(yourDoubleNumber);
int charCount = str.length();
```

it will give you the size of string i.e character count

Comment: people should tell while voting down any answer.

Comment: But it won't work for sure. Because for 5.01 it will return 3 which is completely the incorrect answer. Doubt the upvoters :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doubles and floats don't have chars. They have bits. If you're asking about decimal digits, you would first have to convert to a decimal radix.

Answer (score -3):

```
int method(double value) { 
    if (value == (int) value) 
        return Integer.toString((int)value).length(); 
    else return Double.toString(value).length(); 
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Overload your method with an int argument method, and then apply your logic as before.

```
public int method(double d){
//your logic
}

public int method(int i){
//your logic
}`enter code here
```